# How to get text outline in Android?

Tags: java, android, c++, fonts, intersection

I want to write a APP like [wordle.net](http://www.wordle.net/).

Here is an example image.
https://github.com/danbernier/WordCram/raw/master/wordcram.png

I need get font glyph and text outlines. Then do intersection testing.

I know how do it in Java.

```
public class WordShaper {
private FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(null, true, true);
private Shape makeShape(String word, Font font) {
    char[] chars = word.toCharArray();

    // TODO hmm: this doesn't render newlines.  Hrm.  If your word text is "foo\nbar", you get "foobar".
    GlyphVector gv = font.layoutGlyphVector(frc, chars, 0, chars.length,
            this.rightToLeft ? Font.LAYOUT_RIGHT_TO_LEFT : Font.LAYOUT_LEFT_TO_RIGHT);

    return gv.getOutline();
}
}
```

*This function is get from wordcram.org*

But Android don't have class FontRenderContext, GlyphVector and Shape.

My question is:

1. How to get text outline in Android? I find FreeType, it can port to Android.It has a API FT_Load_Glyph to get one character's glyph. But I need get a word's outlines, not only a character. Is there any library can do this job ,like makShape() above?
2. Is there any equalisation of class Shape. I'm finding a library(Java or C++) that can do intersection testing like Shape.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have find a solution. I use freetype to get every character's glyph, and combine them. So I get a word's glyph. It's a bmp file. And I write a jni lib to use bmp file.

And I didn't find any solution that can do this job in Java on Android platform.